# How to use controlsFX with FXML

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controlsfx

I'm using the ControlsFX `ToggleSwitch` like so:

```xml
<ToggleSwitch fx:id="toggle" onAction="#handleToggleAction" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
```

I want to be able to associate actions on this `ToggleSwitch` with a method in my controller.

This is some of my code in the controller:

```
@FXML
private void handleToggleAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Boolean selected = ((ToggleSwitch) event.getSource()).isSelected();

    if(selected) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //something else
    }
}
```

This is causing me an error:

```
Cannot determine type for property.
```

I don't know why this is causing an error. Before using a `ToggleSwitch` I was using a `ToggleButton` and the handler method was working fine.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ToggleSwitch`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/ToggleSwitch.html) simply does not contain a `onAction` property.

Therefore it's probably best to register a listener in the `initialize` method of the controller:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    toggle.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //something else
        }
    });

}
```